# Adding tiled imagery layers to ArcGIS Experience Builder

Tags: imagery, arcgis-experience-builder

In Web AppBuilder I have a map/app with 11 feature layers and 5 tiled imagery layers that I'm trying to recreate in Experience Builder. I'm not trying to do anything fancy or complicated, I only need to display the layers and configure the pop ups to make it easier for the user to explore the data.

This is my first-time using Experience Builder and so far I've added the web map as data and when I click the Data tab on the left all the feature layers and whether they're in use or not are listed. But none of the tiled imagery layers are listed and I'm not sure why they aren't or what I need to do to add them to the map.

All the feature layers and tiled imagery layers are publicly available on AGO so that shouldn't be an issue. I assumed that tiled imagery can be added to Experience Builder since you can do that using Web AppBuilder, but now I'm wondering if that's the issue.

I started this map weeks ago before the tiled imagery layers were available and am only looking at it again now, so it's also possible I'm forgetting a necessary step I did to get the feature layers to appear.

No amount of clicking around in Experience Builder or searching for guides has gotten me anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After adding data it needs to be linked to a map Widget. One needs to add a map using the Map widget under Map centric tab on the left. Then click on the amp to activate the Map widget, and click Select Map button on the righthand side.

The imagery data are not listed under the Data tab but will display in the Map if you have them turned on in your Web Map (the one you added under Data tab).